# is OpenSearch Security plugin not supported by opensearch-project/opensearch-php?

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

```
$client = $this->searcher->getClient();
dd($client->security()->getRoles());
```

Error: {"error":"no handler found for uri [/_plugins/_security/api/roles] and method [GET]"}